# Inner_join() adding rows together instead of unique rows

Tags: r, dplyr, inner-join

I'm concerned that something is wrong with my R/Rstudio. I'm trying to do an `inner_join()` to get the intersection of male and female baby names from the babynames package, but am seeing that my `inner_join()` is greater than my subset for male names with the following code:

```r
library(babynames)
library(dplyr)

malenames <- babynames %>%
  filter(sex=="M")
girlnames <- babynames %>%
  filter(sex=="F")

names <- inner_join(girlnames, malenames, by ="name")
```

To clarify, I'm seeing rows for 786372 rows for malenames and 1138293 rows for girlnames. What could be going wrong? Thank you in advanced for your guidance.

Comment: "unique rows" plus "do an inner_join() to get the intersection of male and female baby names" plus not "my inner_join() is greater than my subset for male names" does not clearly explain what you want your query to return. Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code & desired output & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) When describing a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to join on both name and year, otherwise each (year, name) pair in `girlnames` gets matched with *every* row with a matching name in `malenames`:

```
names <- inner_join(girlnames, malenames, by = c("name", "year"))
```

Comment: Great, thank you. 
I also was playing around and noticed that piping %>% group_by(name) to the malenames and girlnames dataframes resolves this issue as well. I appreciate the help